# "Localizing" commutative pointed monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, monoid, localization

A *pointed monoid* is a commutative monoid $A$ with a distinguished element $0\in A$ such that $0\cdot A=0$.  Morphisms should preserve $0$.

If $A$ is a commutative ring or pointed monoid, and $f\in A$, there is a localization $A\to A_f$ that is initial with respect to the following property: every map $\phi:A_f\to B$ into a nontrivial ring/pointed monoid $B$ has $\phi(f)\neq 0$.

For both rings and monoids, we get this localization by formally adjoining $f^{-1}$.

What if we have two elements, $f,g\in A$, and we want to study maps $\varphi: A\to B$ into a nontrivial objects $B$ such that $\varphi(f)\neq\varphi(g)$?  Is there a localization $A_{(f,g)}$ with a similar universal property?

For rings, the answer is clear: we can define $A_{(f,g)} = A_{f-g}$.  But is there a more complicated construction that works for monoids?

For example, if $fh=gh$ in $A$, then $h$ should most likely be nilpotent in $A_{f,g}$.

Comment: An immediate obstruction is that for any monoid $B$ and any group $G$, there is always a trivial homomorphism $B\to G$, so you can never have a monoid $B=A_{(f,g)}$ so that every homomorphism from $B$ to a group separates $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Your description of localization does not give a universal property (since it only refers to maps into fields, it cannot uniquely specify $A_f$, since for example it cannot see quotienting by nilpotents). The universal property of localization is that it is universal with respect to maps out of $A$ (and into any other ring / monoid whatsoever) such that $\varphi(f)$ is invertible. It is basically incorrect to think of fields as analogous to groups. Fields are, rather, the simple objects in commutative rings (the ones having no nontrivial quotients).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I agree, I should say instead that it is an initial map with this property.

Comment: And whatever the status of this other construction you want, I think it's misleading to call it localization. Localization should be about inverting things.

Comment: @Slade: The initial map with that property is just the identity map $A\to A$.  You can fix this by requiring that _every_ map $A_f\to k$ is nonzero on $f$.  But then when you try to do the analogous thing for monoids, you run into the problem I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @EricWofsey This is a good point.  I am really working in the category of pointed monoids, and I thought I could get away with a simpler construction.  I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Slade: I'm still pretty sure the first thing you wrote isn't true, at least in the monoid / group case. There are monoids that admit no nontrivial maps into groups at all, and I have no idea how to make sense of the property you're asking for in this case. If your question really isn't about localization then there's no need to mention localization; otherwise I think you're thinking about localization in completely the wrong way.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I have updated the question to reflect that I'm working with pointed monoids, which I had mistakenly thought to be unnecessary structure.  And if this construction exists, it _is_ a localization in the geometric sense.  Since doing geometry with monoids requires congruences rather than just ideals, I was basically wondering if there was a generalization of classical localization to congruences.

Comment: Similarly, in the absence of choice, there are commutative rings that admit no maps into fields at all, and again I have no idea how to make sense of the property you're asking for in this case. Do you really think a definition of localization should depend on whether or not you accept the axiom of choice?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm looking for a definition with a certain property.  The property depends on choice, but the definition should not.

Comment: @Slade: In any case, the problems Eric Wofsey's already pointed out aren't fixed by working in pointed monoids.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see that I need to add a nonzero condition to get the property of $A_f$ on the nose; perhaps I should just describe it as the representative of a functor.  Do you think there are other issues?  Most of the things he mentioned related to "trivial" maps and so forth, which no longer exist for pointed monoids.

Comment: The formulation of the question now looks good to me.  The most recent edit is a nice more natural formulation which I was about to suggest myself.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You can restate it as asking for a reflector from the category of pointed commutative monoids with chosen element $f$ to the full subcategory of pointed commutative monoids with chosen element which can never map to $0$ in a field.

Comment: Okay, at this point I'm happy to at least accept that this is now a question about a universal property.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for being patient. :)  To justify the term "localization", let me point out that we can phrase the universal property for rings geometrically as follows: $\operatorname{Spec} A_f$ is the largest subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ not containing a zero of $f$.  This is a very unnatural definition that relies on choice, but that is exactly why I'd like to find a better characterization in the less well-known case!

Comment: I assume you mean $0.A = A.0 = 0$ ? If this is the case, the standard terminology is "monoid with zero" (and "group with zero" when all elements but $0$ are invertible).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I meant to specify commutativity.  I am not so sure there is a completely standard term here—I was just reading a work of Connes and others with this terminology, but I have also seen "$\mathbb{F}_1$-algebra" in recent publication.

Comment: For a formulation of the universal property that doesn't require the axiom of choice, you could replace "field" with "nonzero ring/pointed monoid" (where "nonzero" means $0\neq 1$).  Since the nonzero objects are exactly those which have maps to fields (assuming choice), this gives an equivalent condition.

Comment: @EricWofsey I agree, that's a nice way to put it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me first explicitly state the universal property we're looking for.  Let us say a pointed commutative monoid is a *field* if $1\neq 0$ and every nonzero element is a unit.  Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the category of pointed commutative monoids $A$ equipped with two chosen elements $f$ and $g$, and let $\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{C}$ be the full subcategory of such objects such that every homomorphism from $A$ to a field separates $f$ and $g$ (call such an object of $\mathcal{C}$ *separative*).  The question is then whether $\mathcal{D}$ is a reflective subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$.  That is, given an object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$, is there a map $A\to B$ from $A$ to a separative object which is initial among all maps from $A$ to a separative object?

Before answering the question, let's discuss some general facts about pointed commutative monoids.  Given a pointed commutative monoid $A$ and an element $f\in A$, the localization $A_f$ can be constructed explicitly as the set of fractions $a/f^n$ modulo the equivalence relation $a/f^n=b/f^m$ if $f^{N+m}a=f^{N+n}b$ for some $N$.  In particular, $a\in A$ maps to $0$ in $A_f$ iff it is annihilated by some power of $f$.  In addition, note that there is an obvious notion of "maximal ideal" in a pointed commutative monoid, and modding out a maximal ideal gives a field.  In fact, in contrast with the case of commutative rings, every pointed commutative monoid in which $1\neq 0$ has a unique maximal ideal, consisting of all the non-units.  In particular, any pointed commutative monoid with $1\neq 0$ has a map to a field.  Furthermore, there is a terminal field $T=\{0,1\}$: every field has a unique homomorphism to $T$ sending every nonzero element to $1$.

Now suppose we have an object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $fg$ is not nilpotent.  We can then form the localization $A_{fg}$, and $1\neq 0$ in this localization.  Modding out the maximal ideal and taking the unique map to $T$, we get a map $A\to T$ which sends both $f$ and $g$ to $1$.  Thus if $A$ is separative, $fg$ must be nilpotent.

On the other hand, if the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$ is not all of $A$, we can mod out the maximal ideal and get a map from $A$ to a field sending both $f$ and $g$ to $0$.  Thus if $A$ is separative, the ideal $(f,g)$ must be all of $A$.  But that ideal is just the set of all elements of $A$ that are multiples of either $f$ or $g$, so this means $f$ or $g$ must be a unit.  The condition that $fg$ is nilpotent now means that the other of $f$ and $g$ must be nilpotent.

Thus we have shown that if $A$ is separative, one of $f$ and $g$ must be a unit and the other must be nilpotent.  Conversely, if one of $f$ and $g$ is a unit and the other is nilpotent, any map from $A$ to a field sends one of them to $0$ and the other to a unit, so $A$ is separative.  So $\mathcal{D}$ consists exactly of those objects of $\mathcal{C}$ such that one of $f$ and $g$ is a unit and the other is nilpotent.  Say that an object of $\mathcal{D}$ is type I if $f$ is a unit and type II if $g$ is a unit.  Note that the only object that is both types at once is the zero monoid $A=\{0\}$, and that there can exist no maps in $\mathcal{D}$ between nonzero objects of different type.

We are now ready to answer the question.  Taking $A$ to be the initial object of $\mathcal{C}$ (concretely, $A=\mathbb{N}^2\cup\{0\}$, with $f=(1,0)$ and $g=(0,1)$), if such a reflector existed, it would have to send $A$ to the initial object of $\mathcal{D}$.  But an initial object of $\mathcal{D}$ would have to be able to map to nonzero objects of both types, and no such object exists.

More generally, if $A$ is any object of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $g$ does not divide any power of $f$ and $f$ does not divide any power of $g$, then $g$ is not a unit in $A_f$ and $f$ is not a unit in $A_g$, so $A$ can map to nonzero separative objects of both types (namely, $A_f/(g)$ is type I and $A_g/(f)$ is type II).  So no such object of $\mathcal{C}$ can have a separative reflection.  On the other hand, if $f$ divides a power of $g$, then $A$ can only map to type I separative objects, so $A$ has a separative reflection iff there is a minimal quotient of $A_f$ in which $g$ becomes nilpotent.  Such a minimal quotient exists iff there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g^{n+1}$ divides $g^n$ in $A_f$, in which case the minimal quotient is $A_f/(g^n)$ for any such $n$.

To sum up, we can say that an object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$ has a reflection in $\mathcal{D}$ iff either of the following two conditions holds:

- There exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ divides $g^n$ and $(fg)^n g$ divides $(fg)^n$.
- There exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g$ divides $f^n$ and $(fg)^n f$ divides $(fg)^n$.

In the first case, the reflection is $A_f/(g^n)$, and in the second case, the reflection is $A_g/(f^n)$.

Comment: This is an _extremely_ helpful answer.  I was just finishing up a concrete proof that $\mathbb{Z}^2\cup\{0\}$ has no separative reflection for its generators, via examining subgroups and quotients of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ explicitly.  But this gives me a lot more than I asked for, in particular this gives me a much deeper understanding of the obstruction than I would have gotten on my own.  Bravo, and I'll definitely award a bounty to this when I can.

Comment: Glad to help; it was a fun question to think about!

Comment: Maybe I'm tired, but is it obvious why the reflection of the initial object is initial?  I suppose it's only necessary that it maps to every other object, which is clear.

Comment: It is obvious.  If $A$ is initial in $\mathcal{C}$, it has exactly one map to every object of $\mathcal{C}$ (including those in $\mathcal{D}$), and so its reflection must also have exactly one map to every object of $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: Oh, I must be tired: I was thinking of the initial object as a limit rather than a colimit.  All clear.